# The \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} problem (Stata - Beamer)

Tags: latex, stata, beamer

When I output a table of regression results from Stata to latex using `esttab, style(tex)`, it includes a phrase -- `\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}` -- at the top of the table code as shown below. I believe this phrase defines my star symbols. I.e., is provided to define `\sym{*}, \sym{**}, \sym{***}` within the tables.

Example:

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
\toprule
--TABLE GUTS--
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
```

However, (1) I don't need this phrase within my latex tables, because I've added this line at the top of my latex doc and tables compile fine without it. (2) For some odd reason beamer can't read tables with this phrase inside. So I can't use the same table for beamer that I'm using for latex.

Can anyone tell me how to either (A) repress this phrase from Stata, i.e. via my `esttab` specification, or better yet (B) allow beamer to read tables that have this phrase in the table as shown above?

Note on Option A: I do realize that I can repress the output by adding `, fragment` to my `esttab`, and then adding the necessary tabular text manually with `prehead(), posthead(), prefoot(), postfoot()`. Maybe I'll go that route. But this is sort of a pain, so I'm looking for a solution that JUST deletes the `\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}` bit. I realize this probably doesnt exist, but I'm guessing option (B) does exist.

I'm working in TexShop on a mac, in case this is a version-specific problem with beamer.

**ADDITION: Here is an example of my problem.** The code below does not compile. However, if you delete the `\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}` at the top, it compiles just fine. Note that I have added [fragile] as suggested, but it doesn't seem to help. Perhaps I have a package loaded that's interacting with the fragile environment, or that's causing the problem in the first place? Some of these packages came with my beamer model I adopted from Cameron Bracken. Others I've added over time for various reasons, and at this point it's a mess of packages some of which I do not need for this particular presentation. So I'm totally up for changing some of the loaded packages if helpful.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  This Beamer template was created by Cameron Bracken.
%%  Anyone can freely use or modify it for any purpose
%%  without attribution.
%%
%%  Last Modified: January 9, 2009
%%

\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% General document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usepackage{float} % Allows my mini-page figure things
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Beamer Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=DeepSkyBlue4} 
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=black} 
 
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

\renewcommand{\(}{\begin{columns}}
\renewcommand{\)}{\end{columns}}
\newcommand{\<}[1]{\begin{column}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\>}{\end{column}}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitems}[circle]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption} % this gets rid of "figure" in front of figure captions

%\usepackage{lmodern} % these two allow me to align math equations w/in columns
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{bbm} % to use indicator function mathbbm{1}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic} % allows to write over pictures
\usepackage{wrapfig} % wrap text around fig

\usepackage{array}          % for this stupid formatting that was automated when i converted from word
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother

\usepackage{chngpage} % to be able to center tables w/ table-specific margins

\usepackage{subcaption}             % allows \tablecaption (again, part of stupid automated formatting)
\usepackage[labelformat=parens,labelsep=quad,skip=3pt]{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}       % tikz package for putting rectangles around tables 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\Wider[2][3em]{%
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+#1\relax}
  \raggedright#2
  \end{minipage}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{{#1}}

\makeatletter
%primitive input in tabular
\AddToHook{env/tabular/begin}{\let\input\@@input}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{Distributional effects: farm size}
\begin{table}[H] \tiny\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
{\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Title}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Title}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Title}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Title}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Title}}\\
\midrule
Null/negative yield effect $\times$ HVY\_{t-1}&       50.98\sym{*}  &       88.84\sym{***}&      -16.71         &      -20.29\sym{*}  &      -0.638         \\
                    &     (29.82)         &     (20.41)         &     (16.74)         &     (10.68)         &     (2.175)         \\
\addlinespace
Positive yield effect $\times$ HVY\_{t-1}&       0.890         &       39.75         &      -34.28\sym{**} &      -4.681\sym{**} &       0.933         \\
                    &     (29.15)         &     (29.44)         &     (13.40)         &     (2.369)         &     (1.240)         \\
\midrule
District FE         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
State-Year FE       &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
Observations        &        1698         &        1696         &        1696         &        1696         &        1696         \\
Within R$^2$        &      0.0118         &      0.0201         &      0.0258         &      0.0149         &      0.0125         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \scriptsize \item Blah blah blah 
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way the content of a beamer frame is handled, you can't just use `#1` within a beamer frame. You would have to double the hash symbol two times:

```
\def\sym####1{\ifmmode^{####1}\else\(^{####1}\)\fi}
```

To use your original syntax, you could use the `fragile` frame option. This changes how beamer processes the frame content:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  This Beamer template was created by Cameron Bracken.
%%  Anyone can freely use or modify it for any purpose
%%  without attribution.
%%
%%  Last Modified: January 9, 2009
%%

\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% General document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usepackage{float} % Allows my mini-page figure things
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Beamer Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=DeepSkyBlue4} 
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=black} 
 
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

%\renewcommand{\(}{\begin{columns}}
%\renewcommand{\)}{\end{columns}}
%\newcommand{\<}[1]{\begin{column}{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\>}{\end{column}}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitems}[circle]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption} % this gets rid of "figure" in front of figure captions

%\usepackage{lmodern} % these two allow me to align math equations w/in columns
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{bbm} % to use indicator function mathbbm{1}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic} % allows to write over pictures
\usepackage{wrapfig} % wrap text around fig

\usepackage{array}          % for this stupid formatting that was automated when i converted from word
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother

\usepackage{chngpage} % to be able to center tables w/ table-specific margins

\usepackage{subcaption}             % allows \tablecaption (again, part of stupid automated formatting)
\usepackage[labelformat=parens,labelsep=quad,skip=3pt]{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}       % tikz package for putting rectangles around tables 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\Wider[2][3em]{%
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+#1\relax}
  \raggedright#2
  \end{minipage}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{{#1}}

\makeatletter
%primitive input in tabular
\AddToHook{env/tabular/begin}{\let\input\@@input}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{Distributional effects: farm size}
\begin{table}[H] \tiny\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
{\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Title}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Title}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Title}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Title}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Title}}\\
\midrule
Null/negative yield effect $\times$ HVY\_{t-1}&       50.98\sym{*}  &       88.84\sym{***}&      -16.71         &      -20.29\sym{*}  &      -0.638         \\
                    &     (29.82)         &     (20.41)         &     (16.74)         &     (10.68)         &     (2.175)         \\
\addlinespace
Positive yield effect $\times$ HVY\_{t-1}&       0.890         &       39.75         &      -34.28\sym{**} &      -4.681\sym{**} &       0.933         \\
                    &     (29.15)         &     (29.44)         &     (13.40)         &     (2.369)         &     (1.240)         \\
\midrule
District FE         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
State-Year FE       &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
Observations        &        1698         &        1696         &        1696         &        1696         &        1696         \\
Within R$^2$        &      0.0118         &      0.0201         &      0.0258         &      0.0149         &      0.0125         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \scriptsize \item Blah blah blah 
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesnt work for me actually. I get the same error as i get without the [fragile], which is "Missing $ inserted". Perhaps it has something to do with what is inside my table -- lines like this with \sym{} on the inside: Null/negative yield effect $\times$ HVY\_{t-1}&     -0.0423         &       0.219         &      0.0188         &   2997556.0\sym{**} &      -107.2         \\

Comment: @LeahBevis The line from your comment will cause an error because you use `_` outside of math mode. Nothing to do with your question above. If you have a new problem, you should ask a new question instead of claiming the solution would not work.

Comment: Incorrect, this is tied to the same problem -- the code DOES run if i do NOT have \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} on the inside of the table, and it does NOT run if I DO have \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} on the inside of the table. I was clear in both my original post and my comment that I do not know why this is -- symbol is a guess. But unlike yours, my table is NOT compiling with \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} on the inside, despite [fragile], and i do not know why. (I.e., if it's the _, then _ is only a problem when I have \def... inside the table.)

Comment: @LeahBevis You cannot use `HVY_{t-1}` in normal text - this is not related to using `#` in the frame. These are two entirely different problems.

Comment: Ok I looked back -- i do not, I have `HYV\_{t-1}` throughout. So I have `HYV\_{t-1}` in about 100 tables in my pdf, and in about a dozen or so tables in a beamer presentation. All compile fine. The problem is that the beamer doe NOT compile if I have the \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} at the top. The fragile does not help. I can try to edit my original post to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @LeahBevis Please add a reproducible example.

Comment: I have now done so. Note that I can't add double hashes; the whole point is that Stata outputs the tables with that particular, irritating line at the top. So I'm looking for something that allows that table to be read by latex as is. I quite literally made a new .tex file that holds precisely the code that I've pasted above; it compiles only if I delete the `\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else(^{#1})\fi}`

Comment: @LeahBevis redefining `\(...\)` as columns isn't such a good idea if you then go ahead and use it for math mode in your definition of `\sym`. Instead of making such cryptic redefinitions which will break all kinds if things, an editor with a good autocompletion for the columns environment might be better.  ... and it would be a good idea to clean up your preamble. Many of the packages are not necessary or don't make sense with beamer.

Comment: Thank you!! So the change you made was to get rid of just 4 lines of the pre-amble? I have no idea what those lines are doing; they came with the original beamer set-up from Cameron. But I CAN compile now, with that deletion + fragile. Can you (1) mention what you are deleting in the answer above, for clarity (otherwise other readers may have trouble following your solution if this ever happens to anyone else), (2) let me know what those 4 lines are code were doing? Like, do I need a substitute for them? Is that going to change anything essential about the beamer presentation?

Comment: see my answer, I commented out the redefinition of `\(` and `\)`

Comment: I have no idea what that means though. You are saying that those 4 lines defined a symbol or output for the code `\(` and `\)` -- is that right? I have never used slashes with parens before. What was that combination designed for (i.e., what would happen when I used those together)? Just wondering if it's something i'll want down the line. Doubtful since I've never used that before, but I imagine Cameron B put those 4 lines in for a reason.

Comment: @LeahBevis I don't think this should be part of the answer. This problem is entirely unrelated to using `\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}` within a beamer frame. Your preamble would have exploded whenever you'd use `\(...\)` somewhere in your code for inline math.

Comment: @LeahBevis You should really clean up your preamble and only use what you need instead of copying such bad ideas from somewhere.

Comment: Huh, ok fair. As long as other people aren't using Cameron's pre-amble I guess nobody else would come up with the same problem. If you could tell me what those 4 lines were meant to do / if I need to replace them with something, I'd love that. But agreed you figured out the solution! Thank you.

Comment: These four lines redefine `\(` and `\)` (which is normally one way to denote inline math in latex) to be a shortcut for columns instead. Really bad idea.

Comment: Clean up my own additions: agreed, will make an effort. However, I wouldn't normally presume to delete part of somebody else's preamble if i'm borrowing a template from somebody else, because i don't "speak" latex well enough to know what all those preamble lines are doing. So this is simply the nature of being a non-fluent user (the normal type of user).

Comment: "because i don't "speak" latex well enough to know what all those preamble lines are doing." That's why using templates is a bad idea. Let your document grow at the same rate as your latex knowledge.

Comment: Ah... so like,  `\(` and `\)` would be equivalent to `$ $`? If so, I actually think I know why -- I think I have seen Stata's esttab automatically output the R^2 label as `\(R^2\)`  rather than $R^2$. I define the label myself when I use esstab, but I think the automatic output uses that code. So you see how for a non-fluent user, knowing this is critical -- now I have to be sure that I always define the R2 label myself when using esttab, never use the default. If you hadn't explained that, I would have been mystified when tables with THAT suddenly stopped compiling.

Comment: Re documents and latex knowledge: i agree that's the ideal. And I will strive harder. : ) But sometimes we all have to use tools we don't 100% understand to function. I NEVER run statistical analysis I don't 100% understand. But sometimes I use vehicular automobiles and latex code I don't fully understand. Life compromises.